# How to crete CounterMutation into Cassandra ITrigger

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using Cassandra 3.10 and I need to calculate how many data modifications I have. For resolving the issue I'm going to use cassandra trigger, but result of triggers work need to be Mutation

```java
public interface ITrigger {
    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update);
}
```

But I have CounterMutation,

```java
@Override
public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update) {
    String keyspaceName = update.metadata().ksName;
    //CFMetaData metadata = Schema.instance.getCFMetaData(keyspaceName, cfName);

    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String cfName = "user_product_count_cf";

    CFMetaData counterCfMetadata = Schema.instance.getCFMetaData(keyspaceName, cfName);
    ByteBuffer key = toByteBuffer("test-user-key");    
    PartitionUpdate.SimpleBuilder builder = PartitionUpdate.simpleBuilder(counterCfMetadata, key);

    ByteBuffer columnName = toByteBuffer("test-counter-column");
    ByteBuffer countValue = CounterContext.instance().createLocal(1);
    builder.timestamp(timestamp).row(Clustering.make(columnName)).add("value", value);

    Mutation mutation = builder.buildAsMutation();
    //TODO this line does not work
    //return Collections.singletonList(mutation);

    CounterMutation cMutation = new CounterMutation(mutation, ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
    //I do not understand what I have to do next.

    //Now I use next line and it is work, but I don't sure that it is good practice.
    return Collections.singletonList(cMutation.applyCounterMutation());
}
```

so how to convert CounterMutation to Mutation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QueryProcessor` class

Example :

```
@Override
public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition update) {
    String keyspaceName = update.metadata().ksName;
    String cfName = "user_product_count_cf";

    QueryProcessor.process(
            QueryBuilder.update(keyspaceName,cfName).with(incr("test-counter-column",1)).where(eq("test-user-key", bindMarker())).toString(),
            ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM, 
            Arrays.asList(key) // Put the partition key value here
    );

    return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

Comment: I insert date to user_event_cf, and want to create count or user_product_count_cf. I thought that I have to create Mutation.
Using cql into trigger is it good practice?

Comment: Check system log Cassandra is throwing exception

Comment: I added some comments to code, that code works well.

Comment: Yes, are right, I lost line where I overwrite metadata variable. Question was fixed .